# PolygonGeometry with offset?Or is there something off with the Mouse events?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, polygon, virtual-earth

I came across the weirdest situation while code-generating polygons and attaching them to a Virtual Earth 3D Globe Control. I have enabled mouse controls, as discussed on this thread in codeplex: http://bingmapswpf.codeplex.com/discussions/279548

**Context:** Map with several polygonGeometries, some of them are intentionally overlayed (using z-index).

**strong text**Actions: Click over a given polygonGeometry or trigger MouseEnter/Leave event over a given polygonGeometry.

**Result:** The object isn't detected by the click or by the MouseEnter/Leave event, however if I apply some "offset" to my clicks/hovers over the PolygonGeometry, the events pickup the object on a "empty space" in the map, a couple of pixels away for the actual object.

**Aditional info:** This behaviour goes away completely if I zoom in the object (almost to a full screen size), and starts getting worse as I zoom out. In High-level views of the map/objects it's impossible to click or hover any objects, or at least they don't get picked up by the events.

So, right now my theory is that by some reason, in lower zoom scenarios, the map "missplaces" the polygonGeometrys (although it seems that they are drawn properly). Being the object missplaced, no shapeId/layerId are detected and thus no action over the event is triggered.

So, I would like to know if someone has already came across this situation and how it was fixed, and/or if I'm doing something wrong on my development (check the mouse events adventure on the post mentioned in the beginning of this discussion), because this is on annoying problem that just doesn't go away... Any suggestion, tip or theory is most welcome!

Thanks in advance for reading and helping. Sorry for any bad english,

-RG

Comment: This API is no longer available